# where should i put getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) in fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I have 3 buttons, "start", "finish" and "go to other fragment" in fragment A. When I clicked "start" button I want to hide back button and when I clicked "finish" I want the back button appears.

This is how I hide back button

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}
```

It's working when I click "start"  button, but when I go to other fragment and back to fragment A, the back button appears. I have tried to hide the back button in `onResume`, `onStart` and `onCreateView`, but it's not working.

This is in my first fragment, before go to Fragment A

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, AFragment.newInstance(),
                            AFragment.TAG)
                            .addToBackStack(A.TAG)
                            .commit();
}
```

This in in Fragment A

```
public static AFragment newInstance() {
    AFragment fragment = new AFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn)
public void goToOtherFragment(){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,
            OtherFragment.newInstance(), OtherFragment.TAG)
            .addToBackStack(OtherFragment.TAG)
            .commit();
}
```

and from `OtherFragment` I just press back button to go to `AFragment`

Comment: Can you please post a code for starting your both fragment also the logic of back from the second fragment, so we can help.

Comment: @angel plz go through my answer it will work because I'm using same to resolve this issue

Comment: @DhavalSolanki I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

If you open FragmentA to FragmentB then you have to `@Override` method in **FragmentB**

```
 @Override
 public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
   ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: honestly i don't want to always hide my back button, i ihave edited my question. thanks before

Comment: @angel add this code to your other two fragments so when you back to AFragment it will hide your back button

Comment: but i can go to FragmentB from other fragment, not only FragmentA, if i add that code in FragmentB, the other fragment will hide my back button too

Comment: on Other fragment onCreate sow the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Hi just replace your fragment code for call fragment B with bellow code it will work

```
public static AFragment newInstance() {
    AFragment fragment = new AFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn)
public void goToOtherFragment(){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(OtherFragment.TAG).commit();
}
```